# Launch xpages application in home screen

Tags: ipad, lotus-notes, xpages, lotus, lotus-domino

I am trying to launch a XPage(web) mobile application from a email(Lotus traveller). When I use a simple HREF in email body (using stream and MIME), xpage(web) mobile application opens in a new window on ipad ( which I believe is expected from Ipad) and displays address bar. The same page when opened from homescreen does not display address bar. I have used following on my mobile page

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

After going through same forum, I tried to launch xpage mobile application on same window of Lotus traveller using the tip of "location.assign"i.e "href="javascript:window.location.assign('http://ajgahsdgasdh.xsp?openpage')". Now the issue is javascript does not trigger from the email body when accessed from Lotus traveller, however same works when accessed from Lotus notes client.I even tried with a simple javascript alert using a button on  email body and the result is same as above. Is this a known issue that lotus traveller will not support javascript? (please note that simple javascript alert is work on Xpage mobile application).Is Lotus traveller a native application, web application or hybrid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lotus Traveler uses the Microsoft ActiveSync protocol when used for iOS devices - and mail is accessed using the native iOS mail application. So any features and limitations that you may experience is not from the Traveler product but from the natiev iOS mail application.

With regards to your inital problem on full screen web apps: full screen mode (as you have seen) only works when the user launches the web app from the home screen - and not when launched directly in Safari.

You can use Javascript to move the content down when the web app is launched in Safari in order for the address bar to be moved out of sight (this does not work on iPad, though). Have a look at this blog post on that subject:
http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-web-apps/remove-address-bar/

Comment: Thanks Henrik. Let me try the options from the link you have mentioned!

Comment: Tried all the options in above link on Mobile Safari version 5.1 on iPad (iOS5). It seems to me that address bar cannot be hidden.

Comment: I have tested with ITANA application available on OpenNTFOrg. Please find the [screenshot] (http://www.openntf.org/internal/home.nsf/discussion.xsp?action=openDocument&documentId=EA55785A36B63CB386257A23001F691C) of the application when accessed from ipad(iOS5) Mobile Safari V5.1

Comment: yes it seems that it is not possible to hide the addressbar on the iPad - probably because the address bar contains tabs for other open web pages and therefore should not be hidden to confuse the user. So the above solution only works in iPhone/iPod Touch.